# Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected string (line 5)

Tags: json

In this creation of an object,unexpected string error appears. Is this declaration incorrect?

```
var all_coupons = {
    "merchant" : hostName ,
    "coupons" : [
        0 : {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[0].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            } ,

        1 : {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[1].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            }
    ]
}
console.log(all_coupons);
```

Comment: check coupon_file.coupon[0].coupon has null value

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `0:` and `1:` indexes - in JSON arrays indexes cannot be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
var all_coupons = {
    "merchant" : hostName ,
    "coupons" : [
        {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[0].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            } ,    
        {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[1].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            }
    ] } console.log(all_coupons);
```

Try removing the index for the coupons array. or

```
var all_coupons = {
    "merchant" : hostName ,
    "coupons" : {
        0 : {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[0].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            } ,

        1 : {
                "coupon_code" : coupon_file.coupon[1].coupon ,
                "coupon_valid" : false ,
                "coupon_status" : false
            }
    }
}
console.log(all_coupons);
```

Turn the coupons array into a map.